# L key not responding on WSL Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, keyboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and am facing some strange behavior. Whenever I press the <kbd>L</kbd> key in the Ubuntu terminal, nothing happens. So, for example, if I type `ls`, all that shows up is `s`. If I type <kbd>L</kbd> on any other window (while the ubuntu terminal is open but minimized), the Ubuntu window comes into focus. However, if I type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, it works fine. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the WSL distro but the problem persists.

I found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1225) concerning the <kbd>D</kbd> key, but the problem mentioned there doesn't seem to apply to me (i.e. I haven't modified /etc/inputrc so that shouldn't be causing the problem).

Does anybody know why might this be happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR : Did you launched WSL using a symlinked exe? If so, then it's a Windows bug due to mistake caused by MSFT engineers.

I've found exactly the same situation on [gsudo's issue](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo/issues/58).

They pinned down the problem to symlink, and then sumbitted to [PowerToy's
issue](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/6621). At there PowerToy's MSFT engineers called conhost's engineer, and they [found a bug in their implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7650)

At there you can see it's fixed in the development branch this Feburary, so you can simply wait the  bugfix, or directly call the exe instead of using symlink

Comment: Huh, that is crazy! Yes I *was* calling it using a symlinked exe, but I could never have even imagined the issue was due to the symlink. It works fine when I call the the exe directly.